# Eclipse CDT can not resolve std::vector of template class

Tags: c++, eclipse, templates, eclipse-cdt, stdvector

I am using eclipse with cdt (Neon.3 Release 4.6.3) as the IDE for C++.

Some code of mine is compiling and running fine, but I have issues with configuring eclipse.

In a header file, I have a template class, which looks like this

```
template <int dimen, int neighbours, typenameDATATYPE >
class Grid {
  public:
    get_solidify_cells(const int &pos)
  private:
    std::vector<MacroCell<dimen, neighbours, DATATYPE>> macrogrid;
};

int Grid<dimen, neighbours, DATATYPE>::get_solidify_cells(const int &pos) {
    const MacroCell<dimen, neighbours, DATATYPE> cell = macrogrid[pos];
    const auto cell1 = macrogrid[pos];
    const auto cell2 = cell;
    return cell.get_solidify_cells();
}
```

`MacroCell` has a method `get_solidify_cells`.

The resolution of the `auto`, when hovering with the mouse over it fails for `cell1`. It thus has no auto completion and `F3` fails to jump to the definition of `get_solidify_cells`

Without `auto` , as this is the case of `cell` auto completion and `F3` are working fine.

If I hover over the auto form cell1 I get `const 1 127 108 14 MSCAFE::Grid 3 10 103 129 5 3 #0 0 10 103 129 5 3 #1 0 #2 MSCAFE::Grid::macrogrid 0 35 MSCAFE::Grid::get_solidify_cells 0 0 cell1`

If I hover over the auto form cell2 I get `const MacroCell<int3 #0 0,int3 #1 0,DATATYPE> cell2`

`C++11` integration works fine, `emplace_back` can be resolved.

How can I configure eclipse, in order to fix this issue?

Comment: Eclipse CDT (just the GUI nothing to do with the compilation tool chain) has difficulty with C++ (auto is one of them, trailing return type being another).  If you can, switch to a different IDE using the same compiler/tool chain.

Comment: @RichardCritten: The issue here has nothing to do with Eclipse having trouble with `auto`. Please see my answer (and feel free to take me up on my challenge and show me an IDE that has the desired behaviour here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reduced piece of code (with different identifier names) that demonstrates the issue:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct Waldo {
    void find();
};

template <typename T>
void foo(const std::vector<Waldo<T>>& v) {
    auto w = v[0];
    w.find();  // would like auto-completion after "w." to offer "find"
}
```

Note that you are asking for auto-completion *inside a template*, and more specifically on an object whose type is *dependent* on a template parameter. This is a **hard problem** in general.

In today's world, it's reasonable to expect that an IDE can do everything that a compiler can, including knowing the types of variables defined using `auto`. However, when it comes to templates, it's important to understand that compilers do very little processing of template bodies prior to instantiation.

Sure, in the above case, a compiler can deduce the type of the variable `w` - for a **specific instantiation** of the function `foo`, with a concrete type available to substitute for `T`. However, it can't deduce the type of `w` prior to instantiation - indeed, the deduced type can potentially be different for different values of `T`. (And I don't just mean that `Waldo<int>` is a different type from `Waldo<double>` - thanks to C++'s ability to **specialize** templates, `vector` could potentially be specialized for some `Waldo<U>` such that its `operator[]` returns a completely different type. Now you and I know that that won't happen, but there is no way for a compiler to know that.)

So, in asking the IDE to provide auto-completion after `w.` - which requires knowing the type of `w` - in an **un-instantiated context**, we are asking it to do something that compilers never need to do, and which can't be done accurately in general.

Now, IDEs (including Eclipse) do employ *heuristics* to try to give useful auto-completion results even in dependent contexts, on a best-effort basis. Unfortunately, these heuristics tend not to be able to see through the copious amounts of template metaprogramming present in typical standard library implementations. (As an exercise, open up your standard library's `<vector>` implementation, and see how `vector::reference_type` (the declared return type of `operator[]`) is defined.)

**@RichardCritten** suggests using a different IDE than Eclipse. I do not expect that to help. Indeed, I invite anyone to show me a C++ IDE that *does* give accurate auto-completion (that's semantically correct, not just "all the identifiers found in the file") for the above code example.